# is there a javascript method for telling us if a input range slider value is going up vs down?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to group input range sliders or 'faders' together so that one 'Group Fader' can control two or more faders while keeping their respective relative values intact.
So if fader One has a value of '50' and fader Two has a value of '75' When we group them together and increase the Group Fader by +20, faders one and two will move simultaneously and have their new new respective values 70 and 95.

I'm playing a shell game with variables and losing.. this is beyond my 'scope'=) hoping there's an easier way. Go easy on me this is my first question.

```js
const faderOne = document.getElementById('one'),
  faderTwo = document.getElementById('two'),
  groupFader = document.getElementById('grouped'),
  output1 = document.getElementById('output1'),
  output2 = document.getElementById('output2'),
  output3 = document.getElementById('output3'),
  output4 = document.getElementById('output4'),
  groupBtn = document.getElementById('grouped-btn')
let locked

faderOne.addEventListener('input', showOutput)
faderTwo.addEventListener('input', showOutput)
groupFader.addEventListener('input', gang)
groupBtn.addEventListener('click', function toggleGrouped() {
  locked = locked ? false : true;
  console.log('grouped = ', locked)
  let groupValue = '0';
  output3.innerHTML = groupValue;


})

function showOutput() {
  let oneValue = faderOne.value,
    twoValue = faderTwo.value,
    groupValue = groupFader.value;
  output1.innerHTML = oneValue;
  output2.innerHTML = twoValue;
  output3.innerHTML = groupValue;
  //console.log(oneValue, twoValue);
}
showOutput();

// if the group feature is 'enabled' (checkbox checked)
//then the Group Fader would control both Fader One and Fader Two respectively. Keeping their relative values intact during any movements the group faders makes up or down

// some way to disable the group fader function and return to the original ungrouped state. or separate function

//let groupLast = groupFader.value;
let groupLast = 0



function gang() {
  let groupValue = '0'
  let groupUp = groupValue
  let groupDown = groupValue
  let groupNew = groupFader.value
  if (locked !== true) {
    output4.innerText = 'You must enable group to use the Group Fader.'
    // Lock? GROUP FADER value at 127 (0-255) to accommodate potential values up and down
    // or hide display of GROUP FADER until checkbox 'enabled'.?
    groupValue = '0'
  } else if (locked === true) {
    //console.log('gang faders')
    //release Group Fader value
    groupValue = groupFader.value;
    output3.innerHTML = groupValue;
    output4.innerText = 'Group Fader is active.'

    //variable for 'previous' Group Fader Value --- is new value higher or lower?
    console.log('group', groupValue)
    console.log('groupLast', groupLast)

    if (groupNew > groupLast) {
      //console.log(control)

      //REPLACE stepUp!

      document.getElementById("one").stepUp(1);
      document.getElementById("two").stepUp(1);
      groupUp = groupFader.value
      groupNew = groupUp
      console.log('groupUp', groupUp)

      output1.innerHTML = one.value
      output2.innerHTML = two.value
    } else if (groupNew < groupLast) {
      groupDown = groupFader.value
      //REPLACE stepDown!
      console.log('groupDown', groupDown)
      groupNew = groupDown
      document.getElementById("one").stepDown(1);
      document.getElementById("two").stepDown(1);
    } else if (locked !== true) {
      document.getElementById('output4').innerText = 'You must enable group to use the Group Fader.'
      groupValue = '0'
      return;
    }
    groupLast = groupNew
    console.log('new', groupNew)
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  font: 1.3rem system-ui;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

input.fader {
  width: 50%;
}

.level {
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  color: #222;
}
```

```html
<input class='fader' type='range' id='one' value='64' min='0' max='127'>

<span id='output1' class='level'></span><label for='one'> Fader One</label>

<br>
<input class='fader' type='range' id='two' value='64' min='0' max='127'>

<span id='output2' class='level'></span><label for='two'> Fader Two</label>

<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="grouped-btn" name="grouped" value="false">

<label for="grouped-btn"> group enable/disable </label>

<br>
<input class='fader' type='range' id='grouped' value='0' min='-127' max='127'>

<span id='output3' class='level'></span><label for='grouped'>Group Fader</label><br>

<span id='output4' class='level'></span>
```

Comment: in my opinion, it would be a better choice to use two buttons for incrementing and decrementing of the two sliders.

Comment: you're suggesting replacing the Group Fader with two buttons? That could work.. ultimately there will be at least 3 and as many as 6 faders. I have a lot of audio engineering experience and the range slider seemed 'natural' i dont know of a html knob.. maybe thats my next question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just store the previous value and use that to calculate how much to change the others. The advantage of this is that is works when the user slides the control and when they click on the slider bar, too.

```js
let control = document.getElementById("range3");
// Store previous value so we can calculate change
control.prevValue = control.valueAsNumber;
control.oninput = (e) => {
  // Calculate the change
  let delta = control.valueAsNumber - control.prevValue;
  control.prevValue = control.valueAsNumber;
  // Update other sliders
  document.getElementById("range1").valueAsNumber += delta;
  document.getElementById("range2").valueAsNumber += delta;
}
```

```html
<div><input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" id="range1"></div>
<div><input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" id="range2"></div>
<div><input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" id="range3"></div>
```